# php string replace with escape characters

Tags: php

Lets say I have a 2 passwords that i am could receive and send on to some other script for processing.

```
$password1 = "gadg$dfglkj";
$password2 = "adsfasdfasdf";
```

If the password has a $ in it, i need to escape the $. how can i achieve this with str_replace?

```
$password = str_replace("$","\$",$password1);
echo $password;
```

doesn't work. I end up with:

```
gadgdfglkj //missing $
```

I have also tried "\$" which produces same result.

The password1 variable is a mysql response in which the password for a given account contains a $.  I get the password back and need to escape it because I am passing that password on to another login application.

Comment: You will get an undefined variable for: `$password1 = "gadg$dfglkj";`

Comment: Just typecast them to a string `(string) $password` and you should be fine.

Comment: Strange output, I would expect `$password1` to be just `gadg`.

Comment: Check with what jlemley said, he is correct. But it might also work to use single quotes in your str_replace function.

Comment: You should never have a problem or need to escape a `$` in a password if you correctly pass the data.  We need more clarity on why you need this function.

Comment: I edited above Devon. does that make more sense?

Comment: Based on your edit, I think the problem with your code lies on how you are passing the data to the other login application but would need to see the code.  If a string from a mysql response is being evaluated by PHP, that is not a good thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the text in single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$password1 = 'gadg$dfglkj';
```

In PHP, single quotes will accept exactly what was entered and not attempt to translate variables. Then if you still need to add an escape character, it should work.

EDIT: 
In order to add in the escape character, make sure to also include the $ character in single quotes for the str_replace function:

```
$password = str_replace('$','\$',$password1);
echo $password;
```

Works like a charm in PHPFiddle.

Comment: That's true but not really an answer to this question

Comment: @Devon, it could very well be the best answer, the OP wasn't clear as to why he needed the $ escaped in the first place.

Comment: @Devon: No problem - I alluded to it, but I'll add in the next step.